# How to call javascript class handler function in aws lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, ecmascript-6, aws-lambda

I am trying to use AWS lambda together with ECMA6 classes in nodejs.
Currently my code looks like this (simplified version of what I really want to do):

```
class testClass {
    constructor(str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    async handler(event) {
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: this.str,
        };    
    }
}

module.exports = new testClass('test');
```

When test this locally with

```
const testClass = require('./testClass');
const result = await testClass.handler();
```

It works as expected, but when I add this to a lambda function and call it, it returns

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'str' of undefined",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "handler (/var/task/index.js:9:24)"
  ]
}
```

So it seems, that the constructor of the class is not called in the lambda context.
Any idea, why this is the case and how to get around this issue ?

Comment: Why would you do this though?

Comment: this is just a simplified version of the code, in the real code the class exports also more functions that are used by other modules for pre-deployment stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use static function inside a es6 class, AWS expect a function with a callback param which will be executed. with the response, if you pass a class method, without instantiate the class, it will not work, that's why you should use static functions, this way:

```
// MyAwesomeClassLambda.js

class MyAwesomeClassLambda {
    static async myAwesomeClassFunction(event) {
        // return await someAsyncMethodLikeDataBaseCallOrSomethingLikeThat()
        return { message: 'hello world' }
    }
}

module.exports = MyAwesomeClassLambda
```

btw the function must be `async`, which is the equivalent behavior to the callback that is passed in the `function` version

In the AWS Lambda console, you must specify the function as: `file_name.function_name`, in this case `MyAwesomeClassLambda.myAwesomeClassFunction`

Comment: I'm getting `offline: Failure: offline: handler 'myAwesomeClassFunction' in /.../.webpack/service/src/handlers/MyAwesomeClassLambda is not a function`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I didn't come up with any solution for this in a ECMA6 class way.
In fact it works as I need it to if I go the old-school way and use a function instead:

```
function testClass(str) {
    const res = {};
    const input = str;

    res.handler = async (event) => {
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: input,
        };    
    };

    return res;
}

module.exports = testClass('test');
```

Even though for my current work it is ok for now, in my opinion this is a bug in aws, as I don't see, why this works when run locally or with a function, but not when run on lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Following will work but since you are not returning anything so you will see null in the response.

```
class testClass {
    constructor(str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    async handler(event) {
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: this.str,
        };    
    }
}

module.exports.handler = (event) => new testClass('test');
```

You can also do something like:

```
class testClass {
    constructor(str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    async handler(event) {
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: this.str,
        };    
    }
}

module.exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const test = new testClass('test');
    return await test.handler(event);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can export the method itself as your handler.

```
module.exports.handler = new testClass('test').handler;
```

Comment: but then only the handler function would be exported, but in fact I need the whole class exported, as also other functions will be used (for pre-deployment stuff)

Comment: I just gave it a try and this doesn't work either.
It fails with the same error message like when exporting the whole class

Comment: @Moamen Edited to fix it.